# Prevent ArrayList from Adding

Tags: java, arraylist

In my program I am converting CAD to USD as an example, when I put in $10 CAD I get $9.14 USD back which is correct. But after that for example I add $50 CAD and convert it, it will display $60 CAD is $54.86 USD when it should convert with only $50 CAD and not 60. This because the numbers in the arraylist are adding and do not know what to do?

[image]
[image]

Here is a photo example

```
private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    double moneyValue = Double.parseDouble(moneyInput.getText());
    int type = Integer.parseInt(typeInput.getText());
    double conversion;
    initialMoney.add(moneyValue);

    if (moneyValue < 0){
        errorLabel.setText("Value added is negative, please try again.");
    }
    else if(type < 1 || type > 20){
        errorLabel.setText("An error has occurred, please try again.");
    }
    else if (moneyValue > 0){
        if (type == 1){
            conversion = initialCADtofinalUSD(moneyValue);
            finalMoney.add(conversion);
        }
        else if (type == 2){
            conversion = initialCADtofinalEUR(moneyValue);
            finalMoney.add(conversion);
        }
        else if (type == 3){
            conversion = initialCADtofinalCNY(moneyValue);
            finalMoney.add(conversion);
        }
        else if (type == 4){
            conversion = initialCADtofinalGBP(moneyValue);
            finalMoney.add(conversion);
        }
```

Here is where it outputs

```
    for (int i = 0; i < initialMoney.size(); i++){
        initialMoneyOutput += initialMoney.get(i);
        finalMoneyOutput += finalMoney.get(i);
    }

    DecimalFormat x = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

    textAreaOutput.append("$" + x.format(initialMoneyOutput) + initialCurrencyAcronym + " is $" + x.format(finalMoneyOutput) + finalCurrencyAcronym + "\n");
```

Comment: How about showing us your code?

Comment: You're adding the second value to the first *somewhere in your code*. How do you expect us to fix it without presenting it?

Comment: You'll need to share some code for us to figure out what's wrong, but without seeing anything, my guess is that you're reusing a variable (the one that holds the amount to be converted) and adding to it somehow.

Comment: The `ArrayList` is not doing the adding; lists only store the object you put in them, they don't act on the object's contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this code:

Instead of the for loop, just write this-

```
initialMoneyOutput = initialMoney.get(initialMoney.size() - 1);
finalMoneyOutput = finalMoney.get(finalMoney.size() -1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList itself does not add the integers if you store them in a list.
Every integer is a new Int object in an ArrayList and it is not related to other values.
There might be some bug in the implementation.
Can you please post the code snippet you are using?

Comment: Added. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize initialMoneyOutput and finalMoneyOutput to 0 just before the for loop where you output it.

Also why do you need to add all the initial money values in that for loop.
Just get the latest one and convert it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I am very new, do you mind helping me through teamviewer or something?